# How to show breadcrumbs of subcategories

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I have a table structure `category_id`, `category_name`, `parent_id` to show multiple subcategories, now I need to show breadcrumb.

I used this recursive function:

```
function breadcrump($catid) 
{
  global $con;
  $s = "SELECT id, parent_id FROM category WHERE id = $catid";
  $r = mysqli_query($con,$s);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_object($r);

  if($row->parent_id>='0'){
    $children = $row->id.',';
    breadcrump($row->parent_id);
  }
  $children1 = implode(",",$children);
  return $children1;
}
$result = breadcrump($catid);
print_r($result);
```

It's only showing result of last id, but not whole array.
and `var_dump($result)` shows null.

Comment: This may be of some help to you: http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Try running your `fetch` in a while loop so you consume all the resultset rather than just one result

Comment: @RiggsFolly still showing null result.

Answer (score 0):

I am guess u are saving just the last result, try to concat the string i mean `$children.=$row->id.','` and then make a trim to delete the las `,`

Comment: still returning null value

Comment: function breadcrump($catid) {
 global $con;
    $s = "SELECT id, parent_id FROM category WHERE id = $catid";
    $r = mysqli_query($con,$s);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_object($r);
 
 if($row->parent_id>='0'){
  $children.=$row->id.',';
  //$children = $row->id.',';
  breadcrump($row->parent_id);
 }
 $children = implode(",",$children);
    return $children;
}